# Both MQ listener are executing MDB on load balancer based Websphere Application Server HADR

Tags: listener, mq

We are facing a critical issue with MQ listeners configured in Active-Active clustered environment of WebSphere application server with load balancer and HADR. Randomly MDB is executing on two nodes upon a message is queued.
 Listeners are configured on two nodes and actually one should listen the message and execute MDB in one server only. However, sometimes two nodes are executing the MDB in indvidual nodes causing business impact.

What could be the root cause and Resolvemwnt.

Comment: MDB processing is happening in two nodes as listeners are configured in two nodes for load balancing. We could able to seem in SYSOUT log. Yes connecting to IBM MQ.

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by "Randomly MDB is executing on two nodes upon a message is queued"? And how is this impacting your message processing?